# How to print the language that word is belong to?

Tags: python, nltk

I want to get print the language according by breaking sentence in to words

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
from langdetect import detect
text = "I like you"
for word in word_tokenize(text):
    try:
        language = detect(word)
        print(word+" the detected "+language)
    except:
        print("Error")
```

Output as follow for English language :

```
I the detected id
like the detected et
you the detected sw
```

Comment: Its hard to guess a language from a single word.

Comment: langdetect can detect a language based on a sentence so why do you iterate through each word? Just try ```detect(text)```

Comment: Short text or single words can confuse the detector. Try longer text; e.g. `detect("I Like You So Much, You'll Know It")` which detects "en".

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in your [Python commandline interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html):

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download("punkt")
```

and then your program should work correctly

Comment: Why would that be the case?